# HTML File Upload Doesn't Show Gallery on Android

Tags: android, html, file-upload, android-gallery

I'd like my PHP app to accept a photo chosen from a mobile user's gallery. I'm testing on Android 4.4.4 using Chrome. This is my form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="index.php" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="20000000" />
  <input type="submit" value="Add" />
</form>
```

I've tried three different `type="file"` inputs and none of them give me the Gallery as an option:

```
  <input name="userfile" type="file" />
```

Options: Camera, Camcorder, Sound Recorder and Documents

```
  <input name="userfile" type="file" accept="images/*" />
```

Options: Camera and Documents

```
  <input name="userfile" type="file" accept="images/*" capture />
```

Goes straight into Camera.

Is there some straight-forward way to get Gallery to come up as an option or do I have do some round-about thing using JavaScript? Thanks for your answers.

Comment: 'the Gallery' is an app. What you get now are file pickers for folders i think. Very different. For what you want you have to start that app. And that app has to store results for your page. Well i dont know how to do that. Or is Camera the app?

Comment: Php app using browser Chrome? Do you mean the new Chromium WebView?

Comment: No, I mean it's a PHP app running on a regular web server and I'm connecting to it using Chrome running on Android. When I connect to the web server using a desktop browser it works as I'd expect.

Comment: You mean php scripts on a webserver.

Answer (score 12):

Try to use  `<input name="userfile" type="file" accept="image/*" />`

instead of  `<input name="userfile" type="file" accept="images/*" />`.

It works for me.

Answer (score 3):

[Turns out this is a known bug in Android >= 4.4](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62220). My code works as expected in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on my Android-Device. Google Chrome had not the right to access the Gallery (Files and Media). If you turn it through Settings->Apps->Chrome on, it works quite well.

I know it's an old thread, but I hope my answer helps others out of the struggle.