# Input file not select in FB in-app browser with Android 11

Tags: html, android-11, facebook-browser

I am using `<input type="file" accept="image/*">`. when I select the input, the file chooser was open but when select the file, it doesn't select. the issue was only happen when open in Facebook in-app browser with Android 11. it working fine with other Browser.

Does anyone have met the same issue like this?
or Having ways to solve the issue would be appreciate.

Thanks, Rithy

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470932/html-file-upload-doesnt-show-gallery-on-android Check this out maybe